# Two line hfill in custom chapter

Tags: macros, horizontal-alignment, chapters

```
\def\thickhrule{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height .5pt \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\position{\centering}
%% Note the difference between the commands the one is 
%% make and the other one is makes
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font
       % {\Huge \scshape  \thechapter }
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{5\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \thickhrule
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
            % hacken om nummer 0 niet te weergeven 
        \hfill {\Huge \bfseries \ifthenelse{\value{chapter}>0}{\thechapter{}}{} #1\par\nobreak}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        \thickhrule
    \vskip 50\p@
  }}

%% This uses makes

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font
        %{\Huge \scshape \vphantom{\thechapter}}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{5\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \thickhrule
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        {\hspace*{0pt}\hfill \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        \thickhrule
    \vskip 50\p@
  }}
\endinput
```

The above code defines a Sony style chapter heading, which looks nice in my point of view.
For proper lay-out, I right align the chapter. However, for long chapter titles this yields a problem, the extra line gets centred.

How to fix this in the above code?

Comment: Change `\hfill` into `\raggedleft`. You'll have to adjust the line breaks by hand with ``\\``.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use a parbox with `\raggedleft`

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrule{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height .5pt \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\position{\centering}
%% Note the difference between the commands the one is 
%% make and the other one is makes
\renewcommand\@makechapterhead[1]{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font
       % {\Huge \scshape  \thechapter }
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{5\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \thickhrule
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
            % hacken om nummer 0 niet te weergeven 
        \noindent
        \parbox{\linewidth}{\raggedleft\Huge \bfseries 
          \ifnum\thechapter>0 \thechapter\space\fi #1}\par\nobreak}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        \noindent
        \thickhrule
    \vskip 50\p@
  }

%% This uses makes

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font
        %{\Huge \scshape \vphantom{\thechapter}}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{5\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \thickhrule
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        \noindent
        \parbox{\linewidth}{\raggedleft\Huge \bfseries #1}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        \thickhrule
    \vskip 50\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{A very long title for my chapter}
foo

\chapter*{A very long title for my chapter}
foo
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Herbert, that was the answer. However 

\ifnum\thechapter>0 \thechapter\space\fi

Did not work. But problem solved, thanks!

@egreg, thanks for modifying my post for correctly displaying the code.

Comment: Small problem:

If only one line is needed, the vertical alignment is false. The text is slighty placed above the center. 

How to fix this?

(the current workstation is crappy, so I can not provide an pdf output example currently)

Comment: delete the `[t]` after `\parbox`